# I'm having problems connecting to TFS VS2010 from VS 2008

Tags: sql, ssis

---

If you are not able to connect to TFS VS2010 from VS2008. This might save you some time.

Connecting from VS2008 to TFS VS2010

Step:1  Make sure that Service Pack 1 is installed with  Sql Server 2008

Step:2  Make sure that Service Pack 1 is installed with VS2008

Step:3 Make sure that Team Explorer is installed in VS 2008

Step:4 Make sure that Service pack 1 is updated for Team Explorer

Step:5  After all these Service Packs are installed on your machine, follow the below path
             CmdPrompt> regedit 
             Hkey_Current_User>Software>Microsoft>VisualStudio>9.0>TeamFoundation> Right Click Servers>New>String Value
Give the complete URL path which look like ‘http://swstfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection’

Step:6  Close everything and open VS2008 
                File>Open>TeamProject

Step: 7 Connect.

I connected to TFS, but the problem is while I am trying to open the solution through VS2008 into TFS it is showing me an error

"This project (fmPilot.SSIS.ClientIntegrations.sln) cannot be opened from source control because it was created by a version of Microsoft Visual Studio that is incompatible with this one.

If this is the case, you may be able to open it from source control using that version of Microsoft Visual Studio, and then use Microsoft Visual Studio to open the local copy."

I also tried it through VS2010 but it is showing me an error

"Cannot be openned because its project type(/dtproj) is not supported bby this version of the application."

Can somebody help me on that..... I google it some says that permission might be the reason.. Please help me...

Thanks,

Karthik

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have `Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)` installed on your machine. Having just Visual Studio 2008 doesn't mean that you can open SSIS packages.

To verify whether you have BIDS installed:

Open Visual Studio 2008 IDE. Click *Help* and *About Microsoft Visual Studio*.

[image: Help - About]

Make sure that you see *SQL Server Integration Service*.

[image: SSIS]

Another way to verify is by trying to create a new project in VS 2008. You should see *Business Intelligence Projects* under *Project types*.

[image: BIDS]

If you do not see this, then it means you don't have BIDS installed on your local machine. You can install BIDS by installing SQL Server 2008 client tools.

Following link shows how to install SQL Server 2008 client tools.

[**SQL Server 2008 Client Tools Installation**](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1807/sql-server-2008-client-tools-installation/)

Comment: Hai Thanks for your reply, But in my system I already have BIDS installed. And whenever I want to open VS2008 I go through BIDS.

Is there anything else I need to check it out...

Thanks,

Karthik